# How to find minimum among variables with excluding variables having zero values in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have 6 variables names D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6. I wanted to find minimum among them but excluding the zeros if any present.

I did same in MATLAB by using below command:

```
D=[D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6];              
D = D == min(nonzeros(D))
```

I wanted to do Same in Verilog. I am able to find minimum in Verilog but facing problem how to exclude variables which have zero values.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
If input: D1=23, D2=0,D3=89,D4=12,D5=65,D6 =88;                 
Then minimum= 12(D4): before sorting it do not include D2.
```

Please gives few hints.

Comment: What if they are all zero?

Comment: Then the minimum will be zero. How i would do this: take first value of vector and call it min. Then loop from 2nd element to n, is any is smaller than min and not equal zero, call it min

Comment: Show what you have tried/accomplished so far (Verilog code that should compile). From there we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suceeded finding the minimum I guess you do a loop comparing each value to the minimum and updating the minimum if the new value is smaller. On that same comparison exclude zero values